# JavaScript "Prompt" command not working when inserting code

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a project that searches through a block of text, then pushes certain values to the properties of an object, but whenever I put a variable inside of the ingamePrices object at near the bottom of this block of text,

```
var testPrompt = prompt("Let's figure out how this works");
var rawUSDValue = 0.125;
function item(craftGamePrice, craftMarketPrice, uncraftGamePrice, uncraftMarketPrice, strangeGamePrice, strangeMarketPrice, genuineGamePrice, genuineMarketPrice, vintageGamePrice, vintageMarketPrice, unusualGamePrice, unusualMarketPrice, hauntedGamePrice, hauntedMarketPrice, collectorGamePrice, collectorMarketPrice )
{
    this.craftGamePrice = craftGamePrice,
    this.craftMarketPrice = craftMarketPrice,
    this.uncraftGamePrice = uncraftGamePrice,
    this.uncraftMarketPrice = uncraftMarketPrice,
    this.strangeGamePrice = strangeGamePrice,
    this.strangeMarketPrice = strangeMarketPrice,
    this.genuineGamePrice = genuineGamePrice,
    this.genuineMarketPrice = genuineMarketPrice,
    this.vintageGamePrice = vintageGamePrice,
    this.vintageMarketPrice = vintageMarketPrice,
    this.unusualGamePrice = unusualGamePrice,
    this.unusualMarketPrice = unusualMarketPrice,
    this.hauntedGamePrice = hauntedGamePrice,
    this.hauntedMarketPrice = hauntedMarketPrice,
    this.collectorGamePrice = collectorGamePrice,
    this.collectorMarketPrice = collectorMarketPrice
}
var ingamePrices = 
{
};
document.write(testPrompt);
```

so that it's like this

```
var testPrompt = prompt("Let's figure out how this works");
var rawUSDValue = 0.125;
function item(craftGamePrice, craftMarketPrice, uncraftGamePrice, uncraftMarketPrice, strangeGamePrice, strangeMarketPrice, genuineGamePrice, genuineMarketPrice, vintageGamePrice, vintageMarketPrice, unusualGamePrice, unusualMarketPrice, hauntedGamePrice, hauntedMarketPrice, collectorGamePrice, collectorMarketPrice )
{
    this.craftGamePrice = craftGamePrice,
    this.craftMarketPrice = craftMarketPrice,
    this.uncraftGamePrice = uncraftGamePrice,
    this.uncraftMarketPrice = uncraftMarketPrice,
    this.strangeGamePrice = strangeGamePrice,
    this.strangeMarketPrice = strangeMarketPrice,
    this.genuineGamePrice = genuineGamePrice,
    this.genuineMarketPrice = genuineMarketPrice,
    this.vintageGamePrice = vintageGamePrice,
    this.vintageMarketPrice = vintageMarketPrice,
    this.unusualGamePrice = unusualGamePrice,
    this.unusualMarketPrice = unusualMarketPrice,
    this.hauntedGamePrice = hauntedGamePrice,
    this.hauntedMarketPrice = hauntedMarketPrice,
    this.collectorGamePrice = collectorGamePrice,
    this.collectorMarketPrice = collectorMarketPrice
}
var ingamePrices = 
{
     var testVariable = "sampleString";
};
document.write(testPrompt);
```

it causes the "prompt" command to stop working. Does anyone know why, or how to fix it?

Comment: invalid javascript: `var ingamePrices = 
{
     var testVariable = "sampleString";
};`

Comment: `var foo = { var` is a syntax error.

Comment: So do I have to make the variables outside of the ingamePrices object, or would I have to do something else?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ingamePrices = 
{
     var testVariable = "sampleString";
};
```

This might be an attempt at one of two things: an object literal, or block syntax which you imagine will contain `testVariable`.  Object literals contain keys and values, they don't contain arbitrary expressions or variable definitions.  As an object literal this should be

```
var ingamePrices =
{
    testVariable: "sampleString"
};
```

Or possibly, if you really did want a `testVariable` as context for some of the contents of this object, then:

```
var testVariable = "sampleString",
    ingamePrices = 
    {
        blah: [testVariable, "a use of testVariable"]
    };
```

If you were looking for block syntax, and lexical variables, then JavaScript doesn't have them.  It only has global and function variables.  Which means cases like this become a self-executing function, purely to provide scope:

```
var ingamePrices = (function() {
    var testVariable = "sampleString";
    ...
    return { blah: testVariable };
})()
```